# What is your favourite 3rd party WinForms.Net graphing tool, and why?

Tags: .net, winforms, graph

By graphing I mean bar charts, pie charts, line graphs, that sort of thing. I've used a couple over the years, but what is your favourite and why?

One tool per answer please (to make the voting easier  :o)

Answer (score 8):

I like [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) it is a free library and produces quality output.  You can tweak the anti-aliasing to work the way it looks best to you and it supports a variety of charts and graphs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've just had an opportunity to play with ZedGraph and it was very straightforward and created a great-looking graph too :o)

Comment: +1 We'ved used ZedGraph for a couple of projects and loved it.  We'll be hard pressed to move to something else.

Comment: +1. ZedGraph is the perfect combination of power, elegance and simplicity. It's the only library I know that fully separates the graph preparation from the rendering. And its source code is a great lesson of design. It includes a FilteredPointList that do points decimation, and can handle *millions* of dots.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is a simple graph and you need little control over how it is rendered you can easily get started with [google chart api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). You just putting an img tag on your site passing parameters in the querystring on the end of the url. You can even customize the output colors etc.

Comment: Not really much of a winforms solution though.  You could do an HTTP request to fetch the image, but I really don't like when desktop apps require that I have a connection to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Infragistics chart](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/winchart.aspx#Overview) control.  Why... because it's part of the library of controls that we already have a subscription to.  That ringing endorsement aside.  Their chart control is very flexible.  It supports many different chart types including the ones you've mentioned.  They also support composite charts (several different charts within the same chart control).  I will warn you though; learning their development style is not trivial.

Comment: Performances are terrible, and the object model is everything but accurate. I quickly trashed it.

Answer (score 2):

[ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/) Is Easy to use, Supports Logarithmic Scales and the best of all it is Free

Answer (score 1):

I always use Zedgraph since this supports XY-scatter and many others don't. For measurements, data-acquisition and elaboration XY-scatter is very important.

Answer (score 0):

[TeeChart](http://www.steema.com/products/teechart/whatsnew.html). I've been using this tool for a few years now, although it is not free (~500€) it is packed with features.

What I prefer:

- axes scale automatically
- automatic colours for different series
- zoom by selecting an area with the mouse
- delivered with excellent code examples of all the features
- and web support for ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

I find [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com/) to be a pretty good library.  A large variety of charts are available with an easy to understand API.  It also has a very reasonable cost.